# Convert rows of text into pandas structure

Tags: python, pandas

I have thousands of rows in a list like the one below that I would like to convert into a pandas table consisting of different columns.

> 2018-12-03 21:15:24 Sales:120 ID:534343 North America
>
> 2018-12-03 21:15:27 Sales:65 ID:534344 Europe

Ideally I would like to to create a pandas structure with the following columns: Date, Sale, ID, Region, and then fill it with values that fit the values.

E.g. so in the first row I have sales = 120, ID = 534343, region = North America and date = 2018-12-03 21:15:24.

Given that I have thousands of rows, what code could make this work?

Comment: Is this stored in a file - .txt/csv ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing your list is in a file, read it first into a string (or into a list already, in which case following code will differ) and then apply code.

To read into a string:

```
with open('/file/path/myfile.txt','r') as f:
    s = f.read()
```

Code for parsing:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

s = """2018-12-03 21:15:24 Sales:120 ID:534343 North America
2018-12-03 21:15:27 Sales:65 ID:534344 Europe"""

sales_re = "Sales:([0-9]+)"
id_re = "ID:([0-9]+)"

lst = []
for line in s.split('\n'):
    date = line[0:19]
    sale = re.search(sales_re, line).groups()[0]
    id = re.search(id_re, line).groups()[0]
    region = line[line.rfind(":")+1+len(id)+1:] # Search from last ":", add one to go over ":" and 1 to skip space
    x = [date, sale, id, region]
    lst.append(x)


df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

df.columns = ['date', 'sale', 'id', 'region']
```

In the example above, I assume everything is loaded into a string. Then I use regular expressions to extract harder part of each line and append everything into a list that. Then I use the pandas.DataFrame constructor to convert into a dataframe.